# jQuery Mobile 1.4 app looking different after Cordova packaging

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

i'm developing a mobile application using jQuery Mobile 1.4. The application looks good if i run it in my web browser (Chrome web browser on my Alcatel POP C3). After packaging the app using Cordova (2.9 ) some colors and border radius are different, and i can't figure out why. I'm not sure of wich part of code could be helpful to find out what i'm missing, so i just post some sample screenshots of my application opened on a web browser, and as a native application packaged with phonegap.

the page on chrome web browser : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTYZt.jpg

same page packaged with phonegap : https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4nmQ.jpg

Could someone help me?

there are jQuery and jQuery Mobile imports :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/pizzapp.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

    <title>Pizzapp</title>
</head>
```

No browser is selected as default browser  (thank you to all for the answers)

I've tried to open the web page with the system browser, and UI components are rendered in the wrong way. So the problem is actually the web container. How could i fix that?

---

**I post some partial solution for those who possibly find the same issue. Buttons had different colors because some buttons where "visited". The css looks ugly because "visited" attribute of theme "A"  and "visited" attribute of theme "B" where overlapped. I solved by commenting the one not used (in this case, theme "A"). Sadly, i've still no idea to how avoid the black rectangle of the button exiting out of round borders.**

Comment: how are you including jq mobile in your project?

Comment: hi, tnx for the reply. This is my code :
<head>
     
        ...other stuff ...
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: is chrome the default browser of your device? (on some devices you can have android browser and chrome but phonegap will use android browser)

Comment: you should edit your post to add code sample instead of putting it in comment (it's quite unreadable there)

Comment: are you using a custom theme?

Comment: it's just included but not used. I also tried to not include it at all, but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely being caused by calling your jquery files from an external source. Though this is allowed, there can be config issues and in general it is a best practice not to do this as the user of your app will have to retrieve the files on each load causing unnecessary data usage from a mobile device.

Try downloading the jquery files you need and including them in your project.

Comment: Done... But it's still the same. Seems like android default browser doesn't show some CSS correctly. I bought my smartphone 2 weeks ago, it's an Alcatel POP C3 so is a very recent model (October 2013) with android 4.3 on it